# How do I detach JProfiler from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jprofiler

I'm trying to analyze a heap dump in MAT, but when I click on the heap I get error "The JProfiler executable could not be found".  JProfiler has been uninstalled on my PC.  I do not wish to have it integrated with Eclipse any longer.

All google results talk about how to integrate JProfiler to Eclipse.  I'm trying to do the opposite.

Comment: You should uninstall JProfiler plug-in through Help->Installation Details->Eclipse Installation Details->Installed Software tag

Comment: I'm unable to find any JProfiler installed information in the "Installed Software" screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delete the folder `com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse` in the `dropins` folder of your eclipse installation.